# How apply regexp_replace spark function for multiple key-values?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let say that there is a Map with key value pair or text like:

```
val pairs = Map(
  "x1" -> "a",
  "1" -> "xf",
  "80" -> "AB"
)
```

Is there a way to add new column with `regexp_replace` invocation in cycle like that:

```
df.withColumn("newColumn", pairs.mapSomeHow((k,v) => regexp_replace(col("originalColumn"), k, v)))
```

E.g. `newColumn` will have value from `originalColumn` with `"x1"`, `"1"`, `"80"` strings replaced.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```scala
df.withColumn(
  "newColumn",
  pairs.foldLeft(df("originalColumn")) {
    case (c, (k, v)) =>
      regexp_replace(c, k, v)
  }
)
```

This will build a `Column` instance from the original `df("originalColumn")` instance by repeatedly applying `regexp_replace` to the result of the previous replace.